# Calling a div from one site into a pop up on another site

Tags: javascript, popup, external

I have two sites. I'd like to call a form contained in a div from one site and display it in a pop up box on the second site. The two sites are on different servers.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Iframe:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

Comment: Hi.  I don't want to show the whole page, just a part of the page. Basically I want to strip out the header and footer of the source page and just show the div containg the form

Comment: Set the page like you desire in one site (change html or css), and then refer to it from the iframe on your second site.